# Add signature on a fully signed envelope/file? Possible?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am thinking of this workflow:

1. Document has only one signature. Signer 1 has completed signature in the file.
2. Reopen the signed file using existing file or envelope id and add an extra signature.
3. Signer 2 completes the signature.

Is this possible? I saw the clone method, how does it work anyway?

Using SOAP API

Answer (score 1):

Once an envelope is in a completed status (Completed, Void) you cannot make changes to the same envelope. You can take that executed doc and create a new envelope with an additional signature, but that causes an audit trail nightmare (certificate of completion only including one signer) and is not recommended.

As for the cloning feature, what it does bring up the envelope up exactly as it was prior to being sent, same base document, same recipients, same tags, etc.